# Display nested JSON data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Afternoon all,

I'm trying to parse data from a nested json object.

For example: `member.accuracy`

Currently, it's returning the result `undefined`.

My code:

**JSON (places.json):**

```
{
"request_time": "2019-05-30T13:48:39+01:00",
"source": "Network Rail",
"acknowledgements": "Contains information of Network Rail Infrastructure Limited. License http://www.networkrail.co.uk/data-feeds/terms-and-conditions/",
"member": [
{
"type": "train_station",
"name": "London Euston",
"latitude": 51.528135,
"longitude": -0.133924,
"accuracy": 100,
"station_code": "EUS",
"tiploc_code": "EUSTON"
}
]
}
```

**HTML:**

```
   <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
    <title>AJAX JSON by Javatpoint</title>  
    <script type="application/javascript">  
    function load()  
    {  
       var url = "http://myurl.places.json?";
       var request;  

       if(window.XMLHttpRequest){    
        request=new XMLHttpRequest();//for Chrome, mozilla etc  
       }    
       else if(window.ActiveXObject){    
        request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for IE only  
       }    
       request.onreadystatechange  = function(){  
          if (request.readyState == 4  )  
          {  
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);//JSON.parse() returns JSON object  
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML =  jsonObj.request_time;  
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = jsonObj.member.accuracy;  
          }  
       }  
       request.open("GET", url, true);  
       request.send();  
    }  
    </script>  
    </head>  
    <body onload="load()">  

    Date: <span id="date"></span><br/>  
    Time: <span id="time"></span><br/>  


    </body>  
    </html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the json file, the member property holds an array, containing one object. To get `accuracy`, you must access it with an index:

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "member": [{
    "type": "train_station",
    "name": "London Euston",
    "latitude": 51.528135,
    "longitude": -0.133924,
    "accuracy": 100,
    "station_code": "EUS",
    "tiploc_code": "EUSTON"
  }]
}
console.log(jsonObj.member[0].accuracy)
```

Be aware that if you're fetching this data from some sort of API, there may be more than one object present in this array in future fetches, and the first element (index `0`) may not be the one you're looking for.